# Not able to restore the database on SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to restore the database using SQL Server 2014, but i'm getting the following error on server version,

[image]

Please let me know what i need to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: this is clearly version issue.It looks like you have downgraded version of sql-server.

Comment: @zero Thanks for replying, where can i get the this version. Will a higher version do the job

Comment: Go to microsoft downloads page, get SQL Server 2014 SP2 and restore it.
Here you can find some quick info about SQL Server versions http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com.es/

Comment: Thank you. Was able to fix it by updating the SQL Server version